# Android: Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Tags: android, react-native, androidx, visual-studio-app-center

Hello I am using AndroidX for one of my application. But due to some reason, I need to remove the support of AndroidX as node_module is creating an issue. Project work's fine with AndroidX. But when I removed then I am getting below error:

Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

I tried with exclude the module from dependency, but error is still there.

Dependancy:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
implementation project(':react-native-sentry')
implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
implementation project(':react-native-camera')
implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
implementation project(':react-native-maps')
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0"){
    force = true
}
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0"){
    force = true
}
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.3"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5"
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.3"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0"
```

Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: what about reverting android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true from gradle.properties file?

Comment: I don't want AndroidX. So I removed the gradle properties.

Comment: Invalidate caches/Restart ?

Comment: Did it many times. As I am using App Center and getting same error at here as well.

Comment: Can you post your dependencies?

Comment: Its too long to send here.

Comment: Update the question with Dependancy

Comment: firebase may internally using AndroidX. Please check in logs.

Comment: Are you talking about com.google.firebase or react-native-firease?